# Meaning of "with him strength took the form of wealth"

Tags: expressions, idioms

This is one paragraph from the story "The Wit of Porportuk" by Jack London

> Porportuk became angry. His pride was touched; his strength was
> challenged, and with him strength took the form of wealth. He would
> not be ashamed for weakness before the world. El-Soo became
> incidental. The savings and scrimpings from the cold nights of all his
> years were ripe to be squandered. El-Soo stood at six thousand. He
> made it seven thousand. And then, in thousand-dollar bids, as fast as
> they could be uttered, her price went up. At fourteen thousand the two
> men stopped for breath.

I don't understand what the idiom "and with him strength took the form of wealth" means.
Also does "El-Soo became incidental" means that she became meaningless for him?

This is written somewhere around 1910, are the above two mentioned expressions used in todays American English?

Comment: It means that demonstrating his wealth became more important than acquiring El-Soo in the auction.

Comment: 'Strength' here must be seen as subjective, 'the measure of his self-worth'. If he suddenly had a heart attack, if a terrible earthquake struck, if a bomb fell on the auction room ... he might well quickly recalibrate.